# Dont allow numbers in a input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hi i have a function which accepts numbers but there's a few problems with it.

1) i want it to accept slashes i.e. '/'?

2) On the first input it accepts letters for some reason.

it binded to a knockout keyup function.

```
 <input id="txtboxToFilter" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" maxlength="10" data-bind="value: Observable.birthdate(), valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { keyup: CheckDate}" />
```

Which then calls this function.

```
  function CheckDate(){
    document.getElementById('txtboxToFilter').onkeydown = function(evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;

      return true;

    }

  }
```

Any body help?

Comment: You bound the function to keyup, and then again to keydown?

Comment: it didnt work without doing that for some reason

Comment: Note that the title seems to contradict your post. A date input would certainly lack much of its utility if numbers/digits aren't allowed. (Or, by "numbers," are you referring to [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)?)

Comment: Have a look at http://craig.is/killing/mice for handling keyboard input ;)

Comment: You can use regex for 'dd\mm\yyyy' format :)

Comment: If I read this correctly, you are executing a function on keyup, that will bind a function to keydown?! Why do you have `document. ... .onkeydown = function(evt) {`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to make input only take numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151470/need-to-make-input-only-take-numbers)

Comment: And when they paste?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Regex:

here is one which will support leap years as well :)

```
^(?:(?:31(\/)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('txtboxToFilter').onblur= function(e) {
    alert(validateDate(document.getElementById('txtboxToFilter').value));
    }


 function validateDate(dob) { 
    var re = /^(?:(?:31(\/)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;
    return re.test(dob);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exe0m3ek/

> NOTE: I have changed the event from keyup to blur, If you only want
>   this on keyup...please change accordingly.

Comment: We can't be born before the 01/01/1600 :D